# Force SpingBoot to use Gson over Jackson

Tags: spring-boot, gson

I am trying to force SpringBoot to use Gson instead of Jackson. I've read most of the articles I've found online and I am still seeing Jackson being used.  Here's what I've done

1. Added

```
spring:
  http: { converters: { preferred-json-mapper: gson } }
  mvc: { converters: {preferred-json-mapper: gson } }
```

in application.yaml

2. Updated POM

   - Added `gson` dependency
   - Added `jackson-databind` to exclusion list in `spring-boot-starter-web` depedency.
3. Added `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)` to main class.
4. Written below `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  
  @Override
  public void extendMessageConverters (List<HttpMessageConverters<?>> converters) {
    log.debug("Setting gson converter");
    converters.add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter(myCustomGsonInstance()));
  }

  public Gson myCustomGsonInstance() {
    return new Gson();
  }
}
```

When running tests in debug, I can see that Jackson is still listed in the HttpMessageConverters list and Gson is not.

---

Update:
This behavior is seen while running live and in the below test class.

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = MOCK)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTestClass {

  @Autowired
  private MyController controller;
  
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp(){
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
    // .setMessageConverters(new GsonHttpMessageConverter(myCustomGsonInstance())) // if I add this, the test passes.
    .build();
  }
  
  @Test
  public void happyFlow(){
    // given
    URI uri = "/test/uri";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    
    // when
    String responseBody = mockMvc.perform(get(uri).headers(headers)).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

    // then
    assertThat(responseBody, wasSerializedByGson());
  }
}
```

Comment: And when you run not from tests (I mean just start the application in debug mode, what do you see)? Also please show the skeleton of the test, depending on the annotation it may behave different?

Comment: Where is your `myCustomGsonInstance()` coming from? Is this a bean inside the ApplicationContext already?

Comment: Just a method in the same class that returns a instance of Gson. Updated for clarity.

Comment: Why are you manually configuring `MockMvc` you should be using `@Autowired` on the `MockMvc`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using the wrong property for configuring the preferred JSON mapper. You are using `spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper` but the correct property is [`spring.mvc.converters.preferred-json-mapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#web-properties). In `application.yaml`, that would be the following:

```yaml
spring:
  mvc:
    converters:
      preferred-json-mapper: gson
```

Comment: Still using Jackson

Comment: Thanks @andy-wilkinson. I spent hours on this. All the articles told me to use `spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper`, but didn't work for me. With this, I don't even have to add Gson converter to the message converter list.
Since SpringBoot 2.3, the `spring.http. properties` have been moved to `server.servlet.encoding.`, `spring.mvc.` and `spring.codec.`

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot comes with `Gson` Auto Configuration support: [Source Code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/gson/GsonAutoConfiguration.java)

So you have to Autowire the `Gson` singleton instance to be used by your `WebMvcConfigurer` in addition to enabling the yaml property:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Autowired
  private Gson gson;
  
  @Override
  public void extendMessageConverters (List<HttpMessageConverters<?>> converters) {
    log.debug("Setting gson converter");
    converters.add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter(gson));
  }

}
```

And the yaml properties borrowed from [Andy Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson):

```
spring:
  mvc:
    converters:
      preferred-json-mapper: gson
```

With this setup Spring MVC is using the same `Gson` instance as the one Autowired in your configuration.

And in your test, it should look like this:

```
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class MyTestClass {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;
  @Autowired
  private MyController controller;

  @Test
  public void happyFlow(){
    // given
    URI uri = "/test/uri";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    
    // when
    String responseBody = mockMvc.perform(get(uri).headers(headers)).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

    // then
    assertThat(responseBody, wasSerializedByGson());
  }
}
```